# Flutter/Dart - Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

Tags: flutter, dart, unhandled-exception, sqflite

I'm a beginner at Flutter and I'm currently following along with a tutorial to built a task planner (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xJSestoFlJ8&list=PLF9bFmu3NqWqchwS3DO9MDSl15IiHQWcr&index=9)

After rewriting the code by hand (the database, etc), when I restarted to app to show the items I saved into the database in the debug console, I got an error saying while working with initstate and setstate

```
Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
```

Here is the code related to the error

```
final TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();
  var db = DatabaseHelper();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _readTaskList();
  }

  void _handleSubmitted(String text) async {
    _textEditingController.clear();

    Tasks tasksItem = Tasks(text, DateTime.now().toIso8601String());
    int savedItemId = await db.saveItem(tasksItem);

    print("Item saved ID: $savedItemId");

  }

_readTaskList() async {
    List items = await db.getItems();
    items.forEach((item) {
      Tasks tasksItem = Tasks.map(items);
      print("DB Items: ${tasksItem.itemName}");
    });
  }
```

and here is the full debug console log

```
E/flutter ( 8249): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
E/flutter ( 8249): #0      new Tasks.map 
package:gatorblocks_rbt/models/tasks.dart:12
E/flutter ( 8249): #1      _TaskPlannerState._readTaskList.<anonymous closure> 
package:gatorblocks_rbt/pages/taskPlanner.dart:105
E/flutter ( 8249): #2      List.forEach  (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:285:8)
E/flutter ( 8249): #3      _TaskPlannerState._readTaskList 
package:gatorblocks_rbt/pages/taskPlanner.dart:104
E/flutter ( 8249): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8249): #4      _TaskPlannerState.initState 
package:gatorblocks_rbt/pages/taskPlanner.dart:24
E/flutter ( 8249): #5      StatefulElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4355
E/flutter ( 8249): #6      ComponentElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4201
E/flutter ( 8249): #7      Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3194
E/flutter ( 8249): #8      Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2988
E/flutter ( 8249): #9      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5445
E/flutter ( 8249): #10     Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3194
E/flutter ( 8249): #11     Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2988
E/flutter ( 8249): #12     ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4243
E/flutter ( 8249): #13     Element.rebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3947
E/flutter ( 8249): #14     ComponentElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4206
E/flutter ( 8249): #15     ComponentElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4201
E/flutter ( 8249): #16     Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3194
E/flutter ( 8249): #17     Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2988
E/flutter ( 8249): #18     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5445
E/flutter ( 8249): #19     Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3194
E/flutter ( 8249): #20     Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2988
E/flutter ( 8249): #21     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5445
E/flutter ( 8249): #22     Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3194
E/flutter ( 8249): #23     Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2988
E/flutter ( 8249): #24     ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4243
E/flutter ( 8249): #25     Element.rebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3947
E/flutter ( 8249): #26     ComponentElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4206
E/flutter ( 8249): #27     StatefulElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4381
E/flutter ( 8249): #28     ComponentElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4201
E/flutter ( 8249): #29     Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3194
E/flutter ( 8249): #30     Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2988
E/flutter ( 8249): #31     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5445
E/flutter ( 8249): #32     Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3194
E/flutter ( 8249): #33     Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2988
E/flutter ( 8249): #34     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5445
E/flutter ( 8249): #35     Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3194
E/flutter ( 8249): #36     Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2988
E/flutter ( 8249): #37     ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4243
E/flutter ( 8249): #38     Element.rebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3947
E/flutter ( 8249): #39     ComponentElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4206
E/flutter ( 8249): #40     StatefulElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4381
E/flutter ( 8249): #41     ComponentElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4201
E/flutter ( 8249): #42     Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3194
E/flutter ( 8249): #43     Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2988
E/flutter ( 8249): #44     ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4243
E/flutter ( 8249): #45     Element.rebuild (package:flutte
```

[Here is a screenshot](https://prnt.sc/sb4kb3)

The app works perfectly fine, it doesn't crash or anything, just fails to properly show the items that I've saved into the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error because you are putting a `int` into a `Text` widget that accepts a `String`.

You can solve that by converting the int using the `toString()` method.

Check the code below: Replace it with your `handleSubmitted` function:

```
  void _handleSubmitted(String text) async {
    _textEditingController.clear();

    Tasks tasksItem = Tasks(text, DateTime.now().toIso8601String());
    int savedItemId = await db.saveItem(tasksItem);

    // convert savedItemId to a string using toString() method
    print("Item saved ID: $savedItemId.toString()");

  }
```

I hope this helps.

**UPDATED**
After going through your code, I can see you are trying to access the field `id` which you didn't define in your `Tasks` constructor.
Why you are getting the error:
`Type String is not a subtype of int index`

Hope this solves your error.

Comment: Thank you for checking over the code, really appreciate it. I am very new to programming and do not quite understand what I'm supposed to do with that information.

I went ahead and added `id` to the tasks constructor, but now it is saying that it does not have enough arguments being passed to it when being called. 

https://prnt.sc/sb5nsg

Comment: You have to find every instance of where you called the Constructor and add the extra field you just added. @JonathanK.

Comment: I've gone ahead and done all that, still had the same issue.

After looking a bit closer to the errors, it seems like I was trying to call the constructor with a variable that I had not even initialized. Removing that line of code seems to have fixed the issue. https://prnt.sc/sb5xvw

Thank you very much for your support!

Comment: Glad it helped. Even after adding the field to the constructor.